# whole document cloning not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on some stuff meanwhile i get into something which i didn't understand core reason behind it.

my idea(good or bad) is to clone a document and add changes to it and then reassign my cloned object into document

```
var tu=document.clone(true);
 getComputedStyles(document)//returns all current css values
tu.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="yellow";//when i print tu and inspect style is visible on body
tu.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.width="100px";
getComputedStyles(tu)//returns all empty values.

document=tu;
```

But every step return without an error but after assigning tu to document my body bgColor is still white.

one more thing why getComputedStyles() are returning empty values?

Comment: Can you post your `clone` function? And how did your `getComputedStyles(document)` work while `document` is not an element?

Comment: That is just createClone function

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got something which might be usefull

```
var documentClone=document.clone(true);
documentClone.body.style.background="yellow";
documentClone.body.style.background="red";`\\many number of operations`


//after many changes
document.replaceChild(documentClone.documentElement,document.documentElement);
//now you can find all your changes..
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.document` is not writeable.

Comment: @bharathmuppa You can reassign parts, e.g. the body.